# How to count/sum this values of the same word in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, conditional-statements

I am confused to count these words,
I've some data like this :

```
web = 1
sistem=1
web=1
sistem=1
web=1
sistem=1
sistem=0
sistem=0
web=0
sistem=0
web=0
sistem=0
web=0
web=0
```

I want to make result like this :

```
web = 3
sistem = 3
```

I'm using array_count_values(), but this result is not good

```
Array ( [web=1] => 3 [sistem=1] => 3 [sistem=0] => 4 [web=0] => 4 )
```

My code like this :

```
 foreach ($g as $key => $kata) {
            if (strpos($cleanAbstrak, $kata)) {
                echo $kata . $ada . "<br>";
                $p[] = $kata . "=" . $ada;

                // print_r($p);
                echo "<br><br>";
            } else {
                echo $kata, $tidak . "<br>";
                $q[] = $kata  . "=" . $tidak;
                // $m = explode(" ", $q);
                // print_r($q);
                // echo $q . '<br>';
                echo "<br><br>";
            }
        }
        $s = array_merge($p, $q);

        echo "<br><br>";

        print_r($s);


        echo "<br>";
        $f = array_count_values($s);
        // print_r($f);

        echo "<br><br>";
```

thank you very much if you are willing to help me

[RESULT THIS CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsw65.png)

Comment: you can check if `$tidak == 0` don't use it no?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but I don't understand much, where should I type it?

Comment: simple with variable i suppose was `$tidak`,  so `sistem=0 <- $tidak`, use a if for check variable and don't use it if is zero. `if($tidak==0){continue;}else{ $q[] = $kata  . "=" . $tidak; ...`

Comment: Where is the data from?  Can you show `var_export($g);` from before the `foreach()` loop.

Comment: $g comes from previous data

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is use a counter like that:

```
$web=0;
$sistem=0;
foreach ($g as $key => $kata) {
            if (strpos($cleanAbstrak, $kata)) {
              
                $sistem=$sistem + $ada;

            } else {
               $web=$web+$tidak
            }
        }
  
  echo 'web='.$web.'<br> sistem='.$sistem;
```

Comment: Have you test it?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to separate word and value.
Second, you need to check the value : if it's zero you let it go (can't hold it back anymore). Else you count the value ; if it's written, i suppose it can be greater than 1 ; if it's not, it should be "word", or nothing (which would greatly facilitate counting).

Something like

```
<?php
$tab = [
'web=1',
'sistem=1',
'web=1',
'sistem=1',
'web=1',
'sistem=1',
'sistem=0',
'sistem=0',
'web=0',
'sistem=0',
'web=0',
'sistem=0',
'web=0',
'web=0',
];

$tab_clean = [];
foreach($tab as $item) {
    preg_match('/([a-z]+)=([\d]+)/', $item, $matches);
    //print_r($matches);
    $word = $matches[1];
    $number = $matches[2];
    for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
        $tab_clean[] = $word;
    }
}
$tab_count = array_count_values($tab_clean);
print_r($tab_count);
?>
```